# Does Cesàro continuity imply continuity?

Tags: calculus, cesaro-summable

Following the known definition "a function is continuous at $x_0$ iff for any sequence $(u_n)_\Bbb{N}$ converging to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(u_n))_\Bbb{N}$ converges to $f(x_0)$", let's say that a function is Cesàro-continuous at $x_0$ iff for any sequence $(u_n)_\Bbb{N}$ whose Cesàro mean converges to $x_0$, the Cesàro mean of the sequence $(f(u_n))_\Bbb{N}$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

Does Cesàro continuity imply the usual continuity ?

I haven't found any counter example, but I'm also unable to find a way to prove that is is true (if it is) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.**

One can prove that if a function $f$ is Cesàro continuous, then $f$ is a linear function and therefore continuous. So Cesàro continuity implies usual continuity.

Comment: Would you mind telling a more hint?
for the linearity.

Comment: I think you're answer is wrong. Consider for example $f: [0,1] \to [0, 1], f(x) = \chi_1$(that is, $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \neq 1$). Then $f$ is Césaro continuous at 0, but not linear